# handle multiple returned data in $http.get() in vuejs

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js

My controller needs to return two variables to the $http.get() function:
how do i access both the returned data in the function?. I am mentioning my code below (the code below handles only one data returned):
My vue instance:

```
var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#userMgt',
    data: {

    },
    methods: {
        fetchUser: function () {
            this.$http.get('../api/users', function (data) {
                this.$set('users', data)
            });
        }
    },
    ready: function () {
        this.fetchUser()
    }


});
```

Then my controller returning the value:

```
public function index()
    {
        $userRecords = AdminUser::LeftJoin('pltblusertype', 'tbluser.usUserTypeID', '=', 'pltblusertype.utID')
            ->select('tbluser.id', 'tbluser.usName', 'tbluser.email', 'pltblusertype.utName')
            ->get();

        $roles = Role::all();

        return compact('userRecords','roles');

    }
```

can i do it like this?

```
var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#userMgt',
    data: {

    },
    methods: {
        fetchUser: function () {
            this.$http.get('../api/users', function (data1,data2) {
                this.$set('users', data1)
                this.$set('roles', data2)
            });
        }
    },
    ready: function () {
        this.fetchUser()
    }


});
```

**UPDATE**
I didn't give to much thought into eloquent relationship while coding..i am new into this....I just fetched the data like this:

```
 public function getUsers()
    {
        $userRecords = AdminUser::LeftJoin('pltblusertype', 'tbluser.usUserTypeID', '=', 'pltblusertype.utID')
            ->select('tbluser.id', 'tbluser.usName', 'tbluser.email', 'pltblusertype.utName')
            ->with('roles')//eloquent relationship
            ->get();

        return $userRecords;
    }
```

User has many relationship with roles. And then pass single variable to this.$http.get()... and then in my view i displayed the user and its multiple role like this:

```
<tr v-for="user in users">
                <td>@{{user.usName}}</td>
                <td>@{{user.email}}</td>
                <td>@{{user.utName}}</td>
                <td>
                    <ul v-for="role in user.roles">
                        <li>@{{role.roName}}</li>
                    </ul>


                </td>
```

Comment: what does compact do? Why don't you write a json with that information?

Comment: this issue came up because i did't give too much thought on relationships. Sorted the data with eloquent relationship and returned it to $http.get()...Problem solved for now...I will research as suggested by you if such requirement comes up. thanks..

Comment: Please write an answer if you think you solved the problem.

Comment: i updated my solution...thanks